# Bluetooth Communication Possibilities

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have a simple question.

I know that when you pair bluetooth headphones to a phone it automatically takes over the sound and it starts playing on your headphones.

Is it possible to program a device so that, as soon as it pairs with a phone, it turns on the phone's flashlight for example?

I know that you can probably program anything to do anything, but I'm curious to know if there are any limitations? **Does Apple restrict developers and engineers from creating devices that tamper with their iPhone (like the flashlight thing)? Or is it pretty much an open market?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very restricted to protect users.

Bluetooth works by communicating over defined profiles. Pairing does not have a side effect (like turning on the flashlight), it just bonds the two devices. To control each other, the devices have to use profiles. For example, when you connect your headphones to a phone, they probably connect both AVRCP (Audio/Video Remote Control Profile) and A2DP (Advanced Audio Distribution Profile). These profiles have very fixed scope so that developers and engineers **cannot** tamper with users devices in unexpected ways.

Apple is especially careful with their devices. For any Bluetooth classic device that wants to implement a profile outside of the [default ones](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387), a MFi chip is required. Bluetooth LE devices are much more open, and users can connect them to their phone either through an app or the OS itself. Apps are able to turn on the flashlight, like you describe, but it requires camera permissions and is not allowed to run in the background.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Devices that use standard Bluetooth profiles such as A2DP, HFP, HID, AVRCP, no MFi chip is required. Devices that use SPP need to MFi certified and contain the chip

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, I clarified the MFi statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could be talking about software as well (the question is vague enough that it doesn't point to hardware only)...

I worked extensively with CoreBluetooth, the framework allows you to create both sides of the connection (transmitter, receiver or client, server; depending on how you want to look at it). Should you wish to create an app on the phone as one of them, and another app an a phone or a mac (or iBeacons) as the other, you'd be able to create that connection and control stuff on the "client" from the "server" and vice versa. You could control as much as the Apple API allows you to control.